# How to forward servername to nested Apache VirtualHost?

Tags: docker, apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

- **NAS:** QNAP
- **Docker Image:** php:8.0-apache

I have a NAS with numerous dockerised services with domains all pointing to the NAS with Apache reverse proxies set up to direct to the correct `Docker Container IP:PORT`.

All of this works great.

I decided to challenge myself by adding a container to host all my toy websites but I can't figure out how to set up the reverse proxy so the `ServerName` in the NAS `Apache VirtualHost` is forwarded to the container's `Apache VirtualHost` to direct to the correct folder.

The site lives in a folder on the NAS `/share/dev/web/sites`.

With configs below, I can browse to `http://sites.mydomain.com/sites` whereas what I want to be able to do is visit `http://sites.mydomain.com`.

I think that my `NAS Apache VirtualHost` is not forwarding the `servername` so the `Docker Container Apache VirtualHost` doesn't know how to filter the traffic.

I've tried a number of different apache settings with no luck, could anyone point the way?

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    image: php:8.0-apache
    volumes:
      - /share/dev/web:/var/www/html/
      - /share/dev/docker-composer/php/apache/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
      - /share/dev/docker-composer/php/apache/custom.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/custom.conf
    ports:
      - 9103:80
```

**NAS Apache VirtualHost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sites.mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.253.53:9103/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.253.53:9103/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Docker Container Apache VirtualHost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sites.mydomain.com

  ServerAdmin webmaster@name
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sites

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost)

> When enabled, this option will pass the Host: line from the incoming request to the proxied host, instead of the hostname specified in the ProxyPass line.

> This option should normally be turned Off. It is mostly useful in special configurations like proxied mass name-based virtual hosting, where the original Host header needs to be evaluated by the backend server.

For your config, something like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sites.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.253.53:9103/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.253.53:9103/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: LOL I was just coming here to add that as my own answer. As so often happens when I compose a question on SOF I find the answer shortly afterwards. Is this the rubber ducky effect or is SOF in cahoots with Google to hide the answer until I post here :P